# Process.Start opens shortcut folder C#

Tags: c#, process.start

I have a folder named `ABC`in a directory and it also has a shortcut named `ABC`. When the `Process.Start(Path)` is given, the process opens the shortcut(ABC) instead of actual folder(ABC).

**My Full Path:** `\\abc.com\afi-dfs\Vaults\abc_Common_Assemblies\ABC`

How can i set the process to ignore the shortcut and open/target the actual folder?

Comment: Opens the shortcut? What? Are you trying to start a .lnk file? Do you have any code?

Comment: Give it a full name such as abc.lnk for it to be distinguished from abc (dir).

Comment: @shahkalpesh Can you be more specific?

Comment: I didn't manage to reproduce that, but maybe try `Process.Start("explorer", @"\\abc.com\afi-dfs\Vaults\abc_Common_Assemblies\ABC")`

Comment: A folder name can always be unambiguously made a folder name by appending a trailing backslash (\ABC\\).

Comment: @KMoussa This worked well.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is simply add `\` to the end of your path string (in order to specify that what you want to open is truly directory).
So, you should do something like this:

```
Process.Start(@"\\abc.com\afi-dfs\Vaults\abc_Common_Assemblies\ABC\");
```